# Create view by selecting different columns from multiple tables in SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Im trying to create a view where specific Columns from 2 tables to be combined.

### My Tables

`Table1(Column1,Column2,Column3)`

`Table2(Column4,Column5,Column6)`

### Expected output

`View1(Column2,Column3,Column6)`

What query can i use to achieve that output?

Comment: `but it doesn't work` what does this mean?

Comment: You have to join your tables on some column.

Comment: I am not a SQL expert but does MS-SQL vs MYSQL matter here?  OP tagged both

Comment: No join condition? Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: works fine if you want a cartesian product

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this???

Comment: User proper `JOIN`

Comment: What's your question????

Comment: Sorry to everyone for the confusing post and tags.This is my first post and im new to sql and was trying to get the output from my post.

Comment: Your query will get those columns. But I suspect that isn't what you were struggling with. When you post questions you need to be careful to be explicit. Things like "doesn't work" are useless. An explanation like "I am getting more rows than I want" are better.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View]
AS 
SELECT a.Column2,a.Column3,b.Column6 
FROM Table1 AS a
INNER JOIN Table2 AS b ON A.ID = B.ID -- your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fourat and jarhl commented above, you need to explicitly define what columns are used to JOIN both tables.  So using the below code change the ID column to the column that relates these two tables, and if it's more than one column the list them all separated by AND.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourViewName
AS

SELECT t1.Column2, t1.Column3, t2.Column6
FROM Table1 t1
   JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have and id to join tables:

```
create view View1
select t1.column2, t1.column3, t2.column6
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

If you don't have and id and want to get mixes columns without relationships:

```
create view View1
select t1.column2, t1.column3, t2.column6
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```